How to retreive all liquidity pool id for a given raydium program
i am trying to get all pool addresses for a given raydium program. I use solana/web3.js and raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2. So i start with this:
    import { Connection} from '@solana/web3.js';
    import { liquidityStateV4Layout}  from '@raydium-io/raydium-sdk-v2';

Then i get raydium program for open book from here:
https://docs.raydium.io/raydium/protocol/developers/addresses
I used OpenBook AMM address (HWy1jotHpo6UqeQxx49dpYYdQB8wj9Qk9MdxwjLvDHB8).
const raydiumProgramId = new PublicKey("HWy1jotHpo6UqeQxx49dpYYdQB8wj9Qk9MdxwjLvDHB8");
  
  async function getTradingPairs2(programId) {
    // Fetch all accounts managed by the program ID
    const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(programId);
  
    const acc = accounts[1617].account.data
    const liqLayout = liquidityStateV4Layout.decode(acc)
    console.log('Market layout dec:',liqLayout);
  }
  getTradingPairs2(raydiumProgramId)

I used here just one random account as an example but it holds also all other account data.
So, I tried to get an id from
liqLayout.quoteVault.toBase58()
liqLayout.baseVault.toBase58()
liqLayout.lpMint.toBase58()
liqLayout.marketId.toBase58()"

following but when I plug the string id's from these 4 (quoteVault,baseVault,lpMint, marketId) in raydium API for instance:
https://api-v3.raydium.io/pools/info/ids?ids=9nFK4Uygcz8QHizksEjY6J4MxfovSYBXYuQ56L9apLuz
(https://api-v3.raydium.io/docs/#/POOLS/get_pools_info_ids) I don't get any data as a response. I do get HTTP response 200, but none of the data. Things like these:
Response body
Download
{
  "id": "aa98ef7a-34ee-4e30-9dca-50d5d8a599a3",
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    null
  ]

however, when I try to pick a random pool address like:
9nFK4Uygcz8QHizksEjY6J4MxfovSYBXYuQ56L9apLuz (I picked it from Gecko terminal)
and plug it in API I get following:
{
  "id": "f9cf227a-ccb5-48c8-97d8-a01754fcfb67",
  "success": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "Standard",
      "programId": "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
      "id": "9nFK4Uygcz8QHizksEjY6J4MxfovSYBXYuQ56L9apLuz",
...
}


So the final question is how can I get via solana/web.js and raydium-sdk-v2 all these id's: (this one 9nFK4Uygcz8QHizksEjY6J4MxfovSYBXYuQ56L9apLuz is just one of them) for particular program (HWy1jotHpo6UqeQxx49dpYYdQB8wj9Qk9MdxwjLvDHB8). Is this even possible? It should be, but for all accounts when I decode data with liquidity layout I get the response with no data. Can someone help me, or give any other guidance related to this topic? For sure, the main idea is to retrieve all these ID's such as this 9nFK4Uygcz8QHizksEjY6J4MxfovSYBXYuQ56L9apLuz (this is pool address) for a particular Raydium program (and in my case, this is open book AMM). Where did I make a mistake?
